# Is it possible to get node alias during hook_node_insert()

Tags: 7, path-aliases

I need to get the node alias during a hook_node_insert() when creating a brand new node. Function [drupal_lookup_path()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_insert/7) returns blank because the node actually isn't created yet per [hook_node_insert()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_insert/7) docs.

Does anyone know of a way to accomplish this or of an alternative to hook_node_insert().

Comment: What do you need the alias for?

Comment: I have a custom cross site posting script and want to set the canonical url. (I know you may ask why aren't you using Feeds but I have super complex logic that I had to implement it with Services)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@David Thomas pointed me in the right direction with his answer. By passing 'return' as the operation to the pathauto_create_alias() function you can get the alias without saving the alias.

Here is my code:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_node_insert().
 */
function hcp_sync_node_insert($node) {

  module_load_include('inc', 'pathauto');
  $language =  pathauto_entity_language('node', $node);
  $uri = entity_uri('node', $node);
  $alias = pathauto_create_alias('node', 'return', $uri['path'], array('node' => $node), $node->type, $language);
  ......
  ......
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A couple of options there, if `drupal_lookup_path` isn't returning the alias yet.

1. Get the alias using [`pathauto_create_alias`](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!pathauto!pathauto.inc/function/pathauto_create_alias/7) without the `_pathauto_set_alias` save part ( update: can use the 'return' option)
2. Add the node id to a cron queue defined with [`hook_cron_queue_info`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_cron_queue_info/7) and get/process the alias in a worker_callback a little later.

Comment: Thanks you pointed me in the right direction. I was able to get the alias using the pathauto_create_alias() but using 'return' as the operation.